# C# & Selenium WebDriver 4.0+ - Microsoft Edge Profile Selection Window Prevents Tests from Running

Tags: c#, selenium, microsoft-edge

When attempting to build tests using Selenium WebDriver 4.10 and C# (.NET Framework 4.5.2) using the following code I receive a pop-up asking to select a profile. From what I understand the code below already is specifying the profile to use:

```
string strEdgeProfilePath = @"C:\\Users\\" + Environment.UserName + @"\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Edge\\User Data";
string strDefautProfilePath = strEdgeProfilePath + @"\\Default";
string strSeleniumProfilePath = strEdgeProfilePath + @"\\Selenium"; // <---- I have deleted this folder and copied the contents of the "Default" folder to no avail.

using (var service = EdgeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(@"C:\Temp\Selenium\Edge")) {
    service.UseVerboseLogging = true;
    EdgeOptions edgeOptions = new EdgeOptions();
    edgeOptions.AddArgument("--user-data-dir=" + strSeleniumProfilePath);
    edgeOptions.AddArgument("--profile-directory=Selenium");
    driver = new EdgeDriver(@"C:\Temp\Selenium\Edge", edgeOptions); // <----- msedgeserve.exe located here
}
```

Even when I select the profile Microsoft Edge does not continue and the test times out.

What can I do to prevent the profile selection and get the test to run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There're some problems in your code:

1. You don't need to use double backslash, backslash is enough.
2. The value for `--user-data-dir` is not right. Using `strEdgeProfilePath` for it is enough.

So the right code should be like this:

```
string strEdgeProfilePath = @"C:\Users\" + Environment.UserName + @"\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data";
...

// Here you set the path of the profile ending with User Data not the profile folder
edgeOptions.AddArgument("--user-data-dir=" + strEdgeProfilePath);

// Here you specify the actual profile folder
// If it is Default profile, no need to use this line of code
edgeOptions.AddArgument("--profile-directory=Selenium");
```

Besides, to avoid running Edge processes errors, you need to follow the back up  steps in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71238056/msedge-failed-to-start-crashed-chrome-not-reachable/71248356#71248356). Please use the backup folder instead of the original folder in the code.

Comment: This worked as well as the link to the other Stack Overflow article. Thank you!